# How to get the default purple/orange wallpaper from previous versions?

Tags: desktop-background

I know there's previous questions about how to get the default wallpapers from previous versions, and I know how to do that. But, how do I get the default wallpaper the purple/orange gradient one? I noticed when you install a wallpaper package from a previous version it installs everything but the purple/orange gradient ones.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure it is a wallpaper and not a color gradient?

Comment: Yes it is a wallpaper. I would like to get the default wallpaper from 15.10. The one that is selected by default when you first boot up Ubuntu.

Comment: you could try getting a live image and copying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to get them by default, but you can see and download them through this website : http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/a-look-back-at-every-ubuntu-default-wallpaper